# error whit List in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

im trying to send a List in a session variable from servlet ComprasController to jsp Compras.jsp, but I have an error in some line and I can not find where it is

this is the servlet

```
ProductoDAO managerProductos = new ProductoDAO();
    List<ProductoBO> carro;
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
    ProductoBO producto;
    if (sesion.getAttribute("carro")==null) {
        carro = new ArrayList<ProductoBO>();
    } else {
        carro = (List<ProductoBO>) sesion.getAttribute("carro");
    }
    switch (request.getParameter("accion")) {
        case "agregar":
            producto = managerProductos.findProductoBO(request.getParameter("id"));
            carro.add(producto);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("carro", carro);
            response.sendRedirect("Compras/Productos.jsp");

            break;
        case "eliminar":
            producto = managerProductos.findProductoBO(request.getParameter("id"));
            carro.remove(producto);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("carro", carro);
            response.sendRedirect("Compras/Productos.jsp");
            break;
        case "confirmar":
            break;
    }
```

and this is the jsp file

```
<%
                        List<ProductoBO> carro = (List<ProductoBO>) session.getAttribute("carro");
                        if (!carro.isEmpty()) {
                            out.println("<table class='table'>");
                            out.println("<thead>");
                            out.println("<tr>");
                            out.println("<td>Producto</td>");
                            out.println("<td>Agregar</td>");
                            out.println("</tr>");
                            out.println("</thead>");
                            out.println("<tbody>");

                            out.println("<h1>Tu carro</h1>");
                            for (ProductoBO producto : carro) {
                                out.println("<tr>");
                                out.println("<td>" + producto.getProNombre() + "</td>");
                                out.println("<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + producto.getProCodigo() + "'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' name='accion' value='eliminar'>-</button></td>");
                                out.println("</tr>");
                            }
                            out.println("</tbody>");
                            out.println("</table>");
                        }
                    %>
```

add: this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8aBh.png)

and this is the ide report
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gen0U.png)
can you help me please.

Comment: "I have an error in some line and I can not find where it is" - so can't we... unless you post a full stacktrace and show us which line triggers the exception, that is...

Comment: You should write what is the error 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: excuse me. Now I have added image of the error in the post.

Comment: Error clearly says that NullPointerException at line 68 i.e. carro.isEmpty() which means carro is null. Change if condition like, if (carro != null && !carro.isEmpty())